# Restore plan cache and buffer pool after database restore?

Tags: sql-server, restore, plan-cache, buffer-pool

When restoring a database, is there a way to restore the plan cache so it doesn't have to be re-created during production use?

Similar question: is there a way to pro-actively restore the buffer cache during or after a database restore?,…. other than to create and run select statements on the tables previously in the buffer cache, a solution which would be time-consuming to create, and inevitably inaccurate.

This is a followup to this question:  "[Does restoring database clear buffer cache and stored proc cache](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/does-restoring-database-clear-buffer-cache-and-stored-proc-cache)".  edit:  This question is a follow-up because I want to know if there is a workaround to get the plan cache and buffer pool back to their source state.

Comment: Isn't this question answered by [Mark](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2374/mark-storey-smith) in the linked question? You can't re-use existing plan cache for a restored database. Also according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the restore command clears the plan cache for the entire instance.

Comment: @kevinnwhat I agree that the docs appear to say that restoring clears the entire instance cache-- however, that is not the case. The cache will only be clear plans for the database that is being restored.

Comment: @Phil,  it's not a duplicate question.  It's a follow-up, as stated in the OP.

Comment: @kevinnwhat,  those links you listed are the reason for my question,  i.e. is there any way around those blockers?

I'll bet there's a third party tool out there that does it, because it's a legitimate need, the commented links notwithstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When restoring a database, is there a way to restore the plan cache so it doesn't have to be re-created during production use?

No.  The caches will have to warm up based on use.  You can [force plans using the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for particular queries if you want, as the Query Store is part of the database, and will be present after Restore.